# Is there any way of adding my name at the top of each page without fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer

I'm just trying to figure out a way to add my name at the top of each page without using the package `fancyhdr`, since I'm having problems with the installation of this package.

Comment: What class are you using? What do you have on the header now?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). `fancyhdr` is part of the big TeX distributions. There should be no need to install it manually?!

Comment: I'm kinda dumb and I'm using Mactex

Comment: @user1286390 I'd call [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/) one of the big distributions. Are you _sure_ `fancyhdr` isn't installed yet? Maybe you should update your version?

Comment: @cgnieder When compiling it does not identify the package, so I think that it isn't installed. Furthermore, I have already updated my version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `report/article` class, for example, create the page style `foo` as below. Just copy and paste to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@foo{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil{Your name}\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil{Your name}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\chaptermark\@gobble
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    }
\makeatother
```

Then, load it using `\pagestyle{foo}` after the `document` environment.

**ps:** Don't forget to edit your name on `\def\@oddhead` and `\def\@evenhead`.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand the part " load it using \pagestyle{foo}".

Comment: I'm using article

Comment: @user1286390, you can use the page style defined loading it with `\pagestyle{foo}` after the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: If you are using `\maketitle` command you could have a problem, but if you have a simple document, it'll work

Comment: @user1286390, I edited since I forgot to insert the code for even and odd pages. Please, copy the code again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `titleps` package, included in `titlesec`. It does essentially the same as `fancyhdr`, albeit not so powerful.

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.  A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).